# Hex Prefix Ethereum - Yellow Paper

Tags: go-ethereum, yellow-paper, rlp, white-paper

I am trying to understand what is Hex Prefix as specified in the [Yellow Paper(Appendix C)](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf), I don't see a similar reference in the whitepaper, but thank's to this awesome [medium](https://medium.com/r/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fethereum.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F12941%2Fin-the-ethereum-modified-merkle-particia-tree-what-do-the-prefix-key-and-value%2F12942%2312942) post I think I got it, but can somebody please correct me if I am stating anything incorrectly or anything I should add, Thanks in advance for the help. My thoughts on HexPrefix and it's relation to the overall picture in *Italics* below:

*Hex Prefix is an encoding of the "Path" to a given value, in Plain English, it means that hey I know a way to get to this house and here is the map. HP enables to efficiently store the path (aka Map)*. *I think of this as the "Key" in the {Key, Value} pair and hence the Ethereum in a very simple way can be looked at an ever-growing list array of tuples of* ***{HP, RLP}*** where **HP** *is Hex Prefix and* [***RLP***](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/RLP) *Apdx B Yellow Paper, hence:*

***World State = [ {hp1, rlp1}, {hp2, rlp2}, {hp3, rlp3} ]***